# Remove attribute from nested fields in xml column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

After trying many answers about how to delete a field from a xml column in SQL, I can't still manage to find a way to delete the same attribute in multiple fields. Currently my xml column looks something like this:

```
<ArrayOfCodes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Code code="001 ">
      <price xmlns="http://..." xsi:nil="true" />
      <salePrice xmlns="http://..." xsi:nil="true" />
      <quantity xmlns="http:/...">1</>
   </Code>
   <Code code="002 ">
      <price xmlns="http://..." xsi:nil="true" />
      <salePrice xmlns="http://..." xsi:nil="true" />
      <quantity xmlns="http:/...">1</>
   </Code>
   <Code code="003 ">
      <price xmlns="http://..." xsi:nil="true" />
      <salePrice xmlns="http://..." xsi:nil="true" />
      <quantity xmlns="http:/...">1</>
   </Code>
</ArrayOfCodes>
```

My task is to remove the xmlns attributes in all of the fields. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Quick dirty way. Treat XML as text and `UPDATE tab_name SET xml_column = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(xml_column AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 'xmlns="http://..."' ,'') AS XML)`

Comment: That works! But I wonder what's the performance cost for running that on millions of lines.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely. XML support is **highly** vendor-specific

Comment: Also: **why** do you want to remove all references to the **XML namespace**? They're there **for a reason!** - don't just remove them - **use them!**

Comment: They take up to 60% of the database space so the space issue has priority.

Comment: How is this XML generated? Is this under your influence or given "as is"?

Comment: Is under my influence to change the way the new ones are generated, which I already changed but was it harder it was to clean the existing ones.